# Name lookup in using-declaration via using-directive

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, using-directives, name-lookup, using-declaration

Is the following program well-formed or ill-formed according to the c++ standard?

```
namespace N { int i; }
using namespace N;
using ::i;
int main() {}
```

I get different results with different compilers:

- Clang (http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/c8vl7XbumyyS6vsw): No errors.
- GCC (http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/immhNeWFCMcCA800): Error: 'i' not declared.

Is this program well-formed or ill-formed according to the c++ standard? References to the c++ standard needed.

I'm trying to figure out for which compiler I should file a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well-formed.

The *using-directive* doesn't introduce the name `i` in the global namespace, but it is used during lookup. The *using-declaration* uses qualified lookup to find `i`; qualified lookup in the presence of *using-directives* is specified in [3.4.3.2 p1, p2] (quotes from N4527, the current working draft):

> If the *nested-name-specifier* of a *qualified-id* nominates a namespace
>   (including the case where the *nested-name-specifier* is `::`, i.e.,
>   nominating the global namespace), the name specified after the
>   *nested-name-specifier* is looked up in the scope of the namespace. [...]
>
> For a namespace `X` and name `m`, the namespace-qualified lookup set
>   *S(X,m)* is defined as follows: Let *S'(X,m)* be the set of all
>   declarations of `m` in `X` and the inline namespace set of `X` (7.3.1). If
>   *S'(X,m)* is not empty, *S(X,m)* is *S'(X,m)*; otherwise, *S(X,m)* is the
>   union of *S(N<sub>i</sub>,m)* for all namespaces *N<sub>i</sub>* nominated 
>   by *using-directives* in `X` and its inline namespace set.

So, for qualified lookup, the first step is to look for declarations of `i` made directly in the namespace indicated by the *nested-name-specifier* (`::` in this case). There are no such declarations, so lookup then proceeds to the second step, which is to form the set of all declarations of `i` found by qualified lookup in all namespaces nominated by *using-directives* in the global namespace. That set is comprised of `N::i`, which is the result of name lookup, and is introduced as a name in global namespace by the using declaration.

I find it worth noting (although pretty obvious) that this definition of qualified lookup is recursive: using the notation in the quote, qualified lookup in each namespace *N<sub>i</sub>* will first look for declarations made directly in *N<sub>i</sub>*, then, if none is found, will in turn proceed to look in the namespaces nominated by *using-directives* in *N<sub>i</sub>*, and so on.

---

For what it's worth, MSVC accepts the code as well.

Comment: I reported the bug to GCC now: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67008

Answer (score 4):

GCC is wrong. Qualified name lookup does consider `N::i`; §3.4.3.2/2 & /3:

> For a namespace `X` and name `m`, the namespace-qualified lookup set
>   `S(X, m)` is defined as follows: Let `S'(X, m)` be the set of all
>   declarations of `m` in `X` and the inline namespace set of `X`
>   (7.3.1). If `S'(X, m)` is not empty, `S(X, m)` is `S'(X, m)`;
>   **otherwise, `S(X, m)` is the union of `S(N`<sub>i</sub>`, m)` for all namespaces `N`<sub>i</sub> nominated by using-directives in `X`
>   and its inline namespace set.**
>   
>   Given `X::m` (where `X` is a user-declared namespace), or given `::m` (where
>   `X` is the global namespace), […] if `S(X, m)` has exactly one member, or if the
>   context of the reference is a using-declaration (7.3.3), `S(X, m)` is
>   the required set of declarations of `m`.

There is only one namespace nominated by a using-directive in your program: `N`. It's therefore included in the union and `::i` is resolved to `N::i`.

Note that GCC is inconsistent with its lookup: Using `::i` in another context is fine.

```
namespace N { int i; }
using namespace N;

int main() {
    ::i = 5;
}
```

This [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af402f5204c6319b). The only difference that a using-declaration makes as a context is shown in the above quote and does not affect the established conclusion.

Comment: @bogdan Well, I saw this question really late (like a few minutes ago only), so I was lucky to get first ;-)